# Visualizing shapefiles on web using SHINY package of R with PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, r

I am using **PostGIS database** to store my shapefiles. Now I want to read those files through `shiny` package of R.

How can I visualize those files on web using **`shiny` package of R** and perform **statistical analysis** on those shape files?

Comment: It's pretty similar to how you plot and analyse data from PostGIS in R. Once you got all that working you can build it into a Shiny page easily enough. The great thing about Shiny is it requires very little modification of working code, you just hook up the UI and the server to run your functions.